# Checkerboard using graphics library

Tags: c++, graphics

I am trying to create an checkerboard with alternating colors. I'm using a vector of rectangles and coloring each individual rectangle.

```
for (int i=0; i<8; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<8; ++j)
    {
        grid.push_back(new Rectangle(Point(i*50,j*50),50,50));
        if (i%2==1)
            grid[grid.size()-1].set_fill_color(Color(lemon_chiffon));
        else if (j%2==1)
            grid[grid.size()-1].set_fill_color(Color(moss_green));

        if(j%2==1)
            grid[grid.size()-1].set_fill_color(Color(moss_green));
        else if (i%2==0)
            grid[grid.size()-1].set_fill_color(Color(lemon_chiffon));
```

I have tried playing with different values to determine what is colored and the closest I have gotten to a checkerboard was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eyrD.png). I know this is a mathematical issue and was hoping someone could help me understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: You're sure you can't just have a vector of non-pointers? It's less to worry about.

Comment: Didn't consider that option. Though it would require a rather large rewrite. I'll probably do that this weekend for practice.

Comment: I haven't done enough refactoring to know how much those tools would help, but take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters use brackets and spaces it makes your code more readable to others, I think this would solve your problem if you have nothing else altering the grid:

```
for (int i=0; i<8; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<8; ++j) {
        Rectangle gridSquare = new Rectangle(Point(i*50,j*50),50,50);
        if(((i % 2) == 1) == ((j % 2) == 1)) {
            gridSquare.set_fill_color(Color(moss_green));
        } else {
            gridSquare.set_fill_color(Color(lemon_chiffon));
        }
        grid.push_back(gridSquare);
    }
}
```

You have 4 situations you need to code for when doing a Checkered Pattern

1. ((i % 2) == 1) && ((j % 2) == 1)  //Both Odd
2. ((i % 2) == 1) && ((j % 2) == 0)  //Odd Row, Even Column
3. ((i % 2) == 0) && ((j % 2) == 1)  //Even Row, Odd Column
4. ((i % 2) == 0) && ((j % 2) == 0)  //Both Even

Now where you went wrong is that you arn't checking Row **AND** Column at the same time. Your current logic is:

- Is Odd Row
- Else Is Odd Column
- Is Odd Column
- Is Even Column

It Needs to be

- Is Odd Row AND Odd Column
- Else Is Odd Row AND Even Column
- Else Is Even Row AND Odd Column
- Else is Even Row AND Even Column

Answer (score 0):

You're actually really close. The issue is that your `if` statements aren't quite right. There's a slightly easier way to do what you want. You want to know if the row and column you're working with are even or odd. When they're the same, you want to color it one color, and when they're different you want to color it the other color. I would do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        bool rowIsEven = ((j % 2) == 0); // Is the row an even numbered row?
        bool colIsEven = ((i % 2) == 0); // Is the column an even one?
        grid.push_back(new Rectangle(Point(i*50,j*50),50,50));
        if (rowIsEven == colIsEven)
        {
            grid[grid.size()-1].set_fill_color(Color(lemon_chiffon));
        }
        else
        {
            grid[grid.size()-1].set_fill_color(Color(moss_green));
        }
    }
}
```